# MAMP remote access website

Tags: web, mamp

I am using MAMP. Basically, to use the website before, I would go to localhost, or my address within the network "192.160.0.11:8888" and it would bring up the website. But now I want to show my friend the website so I gave him my ip address like this: "92.241.xx.xxxx:8888", but when I use this address, the web browser simply hangs there.  I have firewall completely off and my router is set to port forward 8888 to 192.160.0.11:8888.

The reason why it's weird is because if I type any other port, say, 8887, it simply tells me the "Safari can't connect to server". But with the port 8888 (which is the correct one), it hangs there, so something's up.

What am I doing wrong? THnaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be your webserver is setup to only listen to querys for the local ip 192.160.0.11 by default.

So when it sees a request for 92.241.xxx.xxx it ignores is since it's not a ip in the configuration file. I would check to see in the MAMP config for the 'listen' line.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's listening for all interfaces. The listen line is simply "Listen 8888"